# How to log all the processes running inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, logging

After having logged into the container using the command -

```
docker exec -it <container_name>
```

How do I check for all the processes running inside the container? Is "ps aux" the correct way to do it? Are there any better alternatives/approaches?

Comment: To your command put this at end :   bash      then once inside, yes ps  works .... Also try    ps eafww  to view wide output

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is possible to show all the processes running inside a container without login to terminal by using the following command. Of course, it is just like how one can see by using `ps -eaf`, so just add it to `docker exec`.

```
bash $ sudo docker exec -it test1 ps -eaf
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 sh
    7 root       0:00 sh
   60 root       0:00 /bin/sh
   67 root       0:00 /bin/sh
   84 root       0:00 ps -eaf
```

Like it was mentioned, if you are already inside of a container, then just use `ps -eaf` command to see the running processes.

By the way, it is recommended to have one user application / process per container.

Comment: Thanks, Regarding having one application process per container. So, I have a python application which just calls a java jar file , so there is one python process and one java process which is executed for a small time. Should I run them on different containers or will it be an overkill running different containers ?

Comment: What i mentioned is recommended way. Container automatically stops once designated process ends. User needs to stop container explicitly only for long lived processes / container. So, not a over kill. You can choose to run your process in two container if possible. By the way, if this answer is helpful to, then consider accepting it.

Comment: @Rao Using `-a` with `-e` options for `ps` doesn't make any sense, as `-a` **is** `-e` without some special processes. You should read the manpages of programs and options you use before making answers on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 54):

You can use dedicated command **top** to list process in docker container, regardless of the  operating system in container.

```
docker top <container>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I found this after discovering that [https://hub.docker.com/_/debian](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian) slim containers do not contain the command `ps` or `top`.

Answer (score 13):

Extending from the answer of @Slawomir

And With ps option, docker top [--help] CONTAINER [ps OPTIONS]

`docker top <container_id> -eo pid,cmd`